# Getting an error with Ruby/Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium with Ruby. I am new to Ruby, I set it up using this blog  http://testnerdy.blogspot.ca/2009/10/installing-ruby-and-selenium-on-windows.html
and the Ruby script I used is from here -  http://testnerdy.blogspot.ca/2009/10/running-selenium-tests-written-in-ruby.html

When I ran the script, I get this error

SeleniumRubyWindowsTest.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- selenium/client (LoadError)
        from SeleniumRubyWindowsTest.rb:1

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the selenium gem? If so, depending on your version of ruby you may need to do a

```
require 'rubygems'
```

as the first line of the script to pull in all the gem dependencies, which selenium could be one.